# Supporting federated and forms authentication on the same site

Tags: helix, authentication, federated-authentication

We are building a site that needs to support multiple ways of logging in:

- Forms authentication using Sitecore's built-in user database. Users belong to the extranet domain. This part is already implemented and working fine.
- Federated OWIN authentication against a 3rd party service that is fairly similar to Azure AD

**Content access depending on method of authentication**

- Much of the website will be available to anonymous users.
- Forms authentication will give users access to a few more pages (user dashboard etc.) plus additional features on the public pages.
- Federated authentication will in addition to the above allow access to a secure part of the website.

We need to be able to save profile settings for both types of users in Sitecore. I suppose this means that we shouldn't use virtual users.

Our code solution uses the Helix architecture.

I am looking for general pointers on how to go about setting this up, both in terms of what to do on a Controller level and in terms of Sitecore security roles etc. Should we create a new domain for the federated users? If so, can we configure the site to support multiple domains on the same pages? Is this done by creating multiple site entries with the same rootPath in the Sitecore config file?

Thanks

Comment: I'd create roles and set permissions on those. Assign those roles to users on login and control permissions through sitecore

Comment: In other words, stick to the extranet domain for both authentication methods?

Comment: You can have a domain for each if you wish, this would be up to your implementation. 'A Sitecore domain is a collection of security accounts (users and roles)' Have a read: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/security_domains. What I would try to avoid is hardcoding permissions on the controllers (unless you have a good reason to)